# How I integrate SiriExtension to my Xcode 8 app

Tags: ios10

I'm trying to add `SiriExtension` to my app like below steps.

I've integrated Siri capabilities in my app like this:

**Adding capability:**

1- In the project settings, select your iOS app target and go to Capabilities tab

2- Enable the Siri capability

**Adding the extension:**

1- Go to File -> New -> Target...

2- Select iOS -> Application Extension from the left pane

3- Double-click Intents Extension from right

I added Siri Usage Description key in info.plist

I added `INPreferences.requestSiriAuthorization`  in `viewDidload`

But still my app name is not showing in iPhone settings->Siri->Appsupport

What's going wrong?  Please help me.

Comment: hi i found my solution.after i update my os version to iOS 10.1 now it is showing in my Siri app support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Siri is not working in existing project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395903/siri-is-not-working-in-existing-project)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar kind of problem due to deployment target setting for Intent Extension. You have to set Deployment Target according to test device's OS version. You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395903/siri-is-not-working-in-existing-project?answertab=active#tab-top)