# Siri is not working in existing project

Tags: ios, voip, sirikit, callkit

I have to initiate a voip call through my app using Siri. It is working in demo project but when I am adding the Intents Extension into my existing project then Siri is not working anymore.

In system settings the my app is not showing in App Support section. Plist configuration is like:

[image: Here is my info.plist]

Also see the plist configuration of extension:

[image: Extion plist]

Whenever i am giving any voice command it's saying ***"I wish I could, but  < app > hasn't set that up with me yet."***

I have also tried by enabling Siri from capabilities. Let me know what I am doing wrong there.

Thank you.

Comment: `When installing your extension for the first time, Siri may not immediately recognize your app extension and you may need to wait several minutes before you can issue any relevant commands. Similarly, when updating your extension’s Info.plist file, you may need to wait several minutes before Siri recognizes any changes.`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/creating_an_intents_app_extension

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finally I found the root cause, whenever I was adding the **Intent Extension** the default deployment target was set to 10.2(Xcode 8.2). And when I tried on iOS 10.1 device, Siri ignored my app due to that target configuration. That is why my app was not showing in App Support section.

*Please check whether the Deployment Info for your Extension Target covers your device OS version or not.*

[image]

Comment: this didnt solve for me, are you sure you havent done anything else ?

Comment: @JoãoNunes no, thats all in my case

Comment: Solved for me as well - simulator was 11.3 and target 11.4..... There should be a warning for this!

Comment: Thank you so much. I already wasted a day on this before I found your answer. Not sure why it defaults to a different deployment target than the main app.